# PHP SimpleXML grab attribute

Tags: php, simplexml

I using SimpleXML and wanted to get each of different `learner` and its child `rater` attributes, how can I parse it into an individual like:

```
Learner: John

Rater_1_name: John
Rater_1_email: john@domain.com
Rater_1_group: Self

Rater_2_name: Jane
Rater_2_email: jane@domain.com
Rater_2_group: Manager

Rater_3_name: Nathan
Rater_3_email: nathan@domain.com
Rater_3_group: Peers

// and so on...
```

Code to parse:

```
$xml = '
<users>
    <learner name="John">
        <rater name="John" email="john@domain.com" group="Self"></rater>
        <rater name="Jane" email="jane@domain.com" group="Manager"></rater>
        <rater name="Nathan" email="nathan@domain.com" group="Peers"></rater>
    </learner>
    <learner name="Jane">
        <rater name="Jane" email="jane@domain.com" group="Self"></rater>
        <rater name="John" email="john@domain.com" group="Peers"></rater>
        <rater name="Nathan" email="nathan@domain.com" group="Others"></rater>
    </learner>
</users>
';

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
echo $sxe->asXML();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your elements in a foreach() loop as [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) implements the [Traversable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) interface. So something along these lines should get you started:-

```
$xml = '
<users>
    <learner name="John">
        <rater name="John" email="john@domain.com" group="Self"></rater>
        <rater name="Jane" email="jane@domain.com" group="Manager"></rater>
        <rater name="Nathan" email="nathan@domain.com" group="Peers"></rater>
    </learner>
    <learner name="Jane">
        <rater name="Jane" email="jane@domain.com" group="Self"></rater>
        <rater name="John" email="john@domain.com" group="Peers"></rater>
        <rater name="Nathan" email="nathan@domain.com" group="Others"></rater>
    </learner>
</users>
';

$sxe = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach($sxe as $learner){
    $attr = $learner->attributes();
    $name = $attr['name'];
    echo "Learner $name <br/>Rated by:-<br/>\n";
    foreach($learner->rater as $rater){
        foreach($rater->attributes() as $key => $value){
            echo " - $key = $value <br/>\n";
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:-**

```
Learner John 
Rated by:-
- name = John 
- email = john@domain.com 
- group = Self 
- name = Jane 
- email = jane@domain.com 
- group = Manager 
- name = Nathan 
- email = nathan@domain.com 
- group = Peers 
Learner Jane 
Rated by:-
- name = Jane 
- email = jane@domain.com 
- group = Self 
- name = John 
- email = john@domain.com 
- group = Peers 
- name = Nathan 
- email = nathan@domain.com 
- group = Others
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/iRflU)